# Discussion groups 

Tags: permissions, discussion-board

I want to create a discussion group in sharepoint 2010:

> Create a discussion and alternatively add users to the group. Only the
>   group users can participate in discussion.

How would I go about this requirement?

Please answer this: I've been looking for an answer for a month.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is pretty obvious. I don't know your skills in SharePoint configuration, but here is how it goes:

1. You create a new usergroup.
2. You add the users that you want to that group.
3. You create a new discussionboard (If you already have one, forget this step).
4. Go to the Discussionboard's settings and edit permissions for the discussionboard. There you can add and/remove all the groups and users you want, which should be allowed to use the discussionboard.